# L LED on Arduino is constantly on and com is not detected

Tags: led, arduino-leonardo

When I connect the Arduino to the computer, the L LED is constantly on and com is not detected. However, when I press the reset button, the L LED starts blinking for about 10 seconds and com appears. But then he leaves.

Comment: What happens if you upload the Blink example in the moment when the com port appears?

Answer (score 0):

Hold the Reset button down with one hand and start uploading the sketch (like, an empty sketch or the Blink sketch) with the other. Once you see "uploading" release the Reset button.